# passing string value to double array c#

Tags: c#

I currently have a application that reads back the contents of the text file in a string. I want to put all those values in a double array I have created but can't seem to get it to work here is my code :

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
{
    String line =  sr.ReadToEnd();
    x = doubles;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Everytime I run it I get the error "file could not be read: input string was not in a correct format"
Does anyone have any idea whats wrong?

Comment: What is `x` what is `doubles`?

Comment: try to use the full filename instead of just `"test.txt"`

Comment: Show us how you define and initalise your double array.

Comment: `file could not be read: input string was not in a correct format` is that the literal text of the exception? I'm pretty sure it's not. We can't really help unless we know the literal exception text.

Comment: this is how i define x : double[] x = new double [3501];

Comment: this how i define double : double[] doubles = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split('\n'), new Converter<String, double>(Double.Parse));

Comment: this is the catch exception:

Comment: catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Log the exception and quit...                
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            }

Answer (score 1):

```
bool bSuccess;
double value;
bSuccess = double.TryParse("3.14", out value);
```

Comment: This answers his implied question, but if you re-read the OP's question, the problem is on reading the file.

Comment: if you reread the title, you will find it different. so let's wait OP to clarify.

Comment: double[] x = new double [3501]; double[] doubles = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split('\n'), new Converter<String, double>(Double.Parse));

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file path is delcared for the StreamReader, simply stating "test.txt" with no apparent location does not access the file you are attempting to read from.